# Replacing default jqgrid dialog with sweetAlert

Tags: dialog, jqgrid, sweetalert

I'm trying to replace the jqgrid default delete dialog popup with sweetalert jquery. When I use the code below for delete button, it works fine, but it still shows the default jqgrid delete confirmation method.

Any idea on how to correctly call sweetalert confirmation dialog?
Thanks

```
    url: editUrl,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    closeAfterDelete: true,
    recreateForm: true,   
    beforeShowForm: function ($form) {
    swal({
                                title: "Are you sure?",
                                text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
                                type: "warning",
                                showCancelButton: true,
                                confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                                confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
                                closeOnConfirm: false
                            }, function () {
swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
                            });
                    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it this way. The approach that you use is get from stackoverflow demo which replace the text in the existing dialog. It does not replace the dialog as itself.

To do what you want I recommend you to create a custom navigator button and define your own ajax function to delete the row again with your dialog. Do not forget to use in this case delRowData to delete the row locally too.